# Invert Table to Prepare for VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a table which is really long and looks like this

```
123 | ABC
123 | EFG
123 | HIJ
456 | KLM
456 | NOP
```

and I need it to look like this

```
123 | ABC | EFG | HIJ
456 | KLM | NOP
```

How do I do this in Excel 2010?

Any help will be appreciated!

Kind Regards 
Daniel

Comment: Quick clarification: how many columns in the input? How many columns in the output? Is the data sorted by the 123 "column"? How many repetitions of e.g. 123 are likely (finite number?) These will help with finding best approach.

Comment: There are 5966 columns thus the output should have 5966 rows. The number of repitions varies. The data is sorted by the "123" column, meaning that similar entries are underneath each other.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to get the job done. It assumes the data is sorted by Column A. This code puts the new table on Sheet 2.

```
Sub fun()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim newSorter As Integer
    Dim oldSorter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer

    oldSorter = 0
    newRow = 1

    lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(6000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        newSorter = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
        If newSorter = oldSorter Then 'Add item to right of last entry
            lastCol = Sheets(2).Cells(newRow - 1, 50).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find last column
            Sheets(2).Cells(newRow - 1, lastCol + 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value

        Else 'Create new row
            Sheets(2).Cells(newRow, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
            Sheets(2).Cells(newRow, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
            newRow = newRow + 1
        End If
        oldSorter = newSorter
    Next i

End Sub
```